# Cannot run my Snap package (built from Rust App)

Tags: rust, snapcraft

This is how my snapcraft.yaml looks like (at the root of my Rust project):

```
name: keval-snap 
base: core20 
version: '0.1'
summary: Single-line elevator pitch for your amazing snap # 79 char long summary
description: |
  This is my-snap's description. You have a paragraph or two to tell the
  most important story about your snap. Keep it under 100 words though,
  we live in tweetspace and your description wants to look good in the snap
  store.

grade: stable
confinement: strict

apps:
  keval-snap:
    command: bin/keval-snap
    daemon: simple

parts:
  my-part:
    plugin: rust
    source: .
    build-packages:
      - pkg-config
      - libssl-dev
```

And my Cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
default-run = "keval-snap"

[[bin]] # Bin to run the http client
name = "keval-snap"
path = "src/main.rs"
doc = false
.............
```

After creating the YAML I did

`snapcraft`

`snapcraft upload --release=stable keval-snap_0.1_amd64.snap`

I can see my package on my Snapcraft account

Then, I Installed with `snap install keval-snap`

The only thing is when I run `keval-snap --help` it says command not found !

I expect to see the possible commands and options here.

Is there anything wrong with snapcraft.yaml OR cargo.toml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was mismatching names.
I used `snapcraft --debug` and saw all the files inside VM.

Turns out, application command name should match with part name.
I had my code built inside `bin/my-part`, and I was calling the command `bin/keval-snap`

Changed my part name to `keval-snap` & Issue was resolved !